# LINQ FirstOrDefault() only working with ConcurrentBag<T>

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, azure

Here's a fairly simple, three part task. The first part is getting data from a database. No problem. The second part is parsing that data (done here using an adapter for mockability in testing). Again, no problem. Finally, for a many to many relationship, get all the requested data and allocate it accordingly. Also works, but with a catch. In the following code...

```
var customers = new ConcurrentBag<Customer>(); /* or List<Customer>(); */

// populate the initial customer data...

var customerAddresses = data[Manifest.CustomerAddresses].Select(r => new CustomerAddress
{
    CustomerId = QueryUtility.GetInt32FromRow(r, "customer_id"),
    AddressId = QueryUtility.GetInt32FromRow(r, "address_id")
});

var addressIds = customerAddresses.Select(x => x.AddressId).Distinct().ToList();
var addresses = _addressRepository.GetAddresses(addressIds, manifest);

foreach (var customerAddress in customerAddresses)
{
    var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customerAddress.CustomerId);
    var address = addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customerAddress.AddressId);

    if (customer != null && address != null) customer.Addresses.Add(address);
}
```

... updating objects in the `customers` collection only works when it's a `ConcurrentBag<Customer>`. If the collection is `List<Customer>` the code goes through all the motions, selects the right customer, the right address, seems to add it, but next iteration, there's no update to the object in the collection. Why is that happening? The only reason I would've even thought to use `` `ConcurrentBag<T> `` was because this happened in another repository but it had paralellized actions and I thought it was a concurrency issue in play even though it shouldn't have been. Now I'm second-guessing how I'm resolving this and why it's happening.

Relevant details: Visual Studio 2012, WCF service in a Windows Azure Web Worker, .NET 4.5. Any insight would be very welcome...

**UPDATE:** Here are the entities in question to make it a little more clear.

The `CustomerAddress` class is to help resolve the many-to-many-relationship.

```
public class CustomerAddress
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

The Customer class holds some basic customer data.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ ... ] 
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

And the Address is just that, an address.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: Is there a typo? I assume the last assignment is meant to be `customerAddresses.Add(...)`?

Comment: I'm confused - what is the code actually doing? There is a collection of customerAddresses initialized at the beginning, then you get addresses for all the address - [edit: just realized these are used later, sorry], and at the end you loop over the initial collection, get the customer and address and assign it to some other collection `customers` (or is it the same collection with a typo?). Which one is the ConcurrentBag at all? And what is `customers` - where does it come from?

Comment: No, `customer` is the selected object from a collection and it has a property of type `List<Address>` called `Addresses`. The object to which you're referring is just a link entity.

Comment: Joanna, I put up the basic class structure. The `customers` collection is declared before all this and is updated with customer information before I check whether I also need to get a list of addresses for the customer and do so if the addresses have been requested.

Comment: What's the "next iteration?" The next iteration of foreach? The next iteration of a web request? Even if `customers` were a `List<Customer>`, it looks like it should work. Are you not persisting the updated List back somewhere? Perhaps wherever you are initializing your `ConcurrentBag<Customer>` from, it is a reference to an object already with persistence.

Comment: Maxwell, yes, it's the next iteration of `foreach`. The address was just added, then if you look at what the `customers` collection contains for the customer you just updated, the `Addresses` are resolutely empty. And what do you mean by persistence? I'm taking data from the database and loading them into objects in memory, simple as that.

Comment: It's a pretty long shot but since there is linq in play and everything else looks just right - could it be something to do with actually materializing the data from the customers query? When you initialize `customers` as List and as ConcurrentBag - do you execute exactly the same code?

Comment: Joanna... it's the exact same code. The only difference is the collection type. My only possible thought is that Azure Web Roles have something to do with this but I don't have sufficient evidence to say that definitively.

Comment: This doesn't sound possible. You're *certain* that the code works when you use `ConcurrentBag`, but if the only change you make is to replace that with `List`, then the code doesn't work? I strongly suggest that you post a self contained reproducible example that illustrates this behavior (i.e. something that I can run on my machine). Absent that, I suggest you look somewhere else for the bug in your program.